# Using unity location with external GPS devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gps

I am developing an applciation for android using Unity3D. My application usnig [GPS location service](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html) of unity.

So I have an external South Galaxy RTK device. And I downloaded an applciation named [GNSS Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.pilablu.gnsscommander) that connects to [South Galaxy RTK device](https://geo-matching.com/gnss-receivers/galaxy-g1) using bluetoth and mocks the phone GPS.

After I connected to device, does Unity use the external device or does unity always uses internal GPS device of phone?

What does `Input.location.lastData` gives me? Internal mobile device GPS location or external RTK GPS device location.

Comment: Does your app include the permission to see mock locations?  If so, and you're mocking location it will see the mock.  If not, you'll never see the mock.

Comment: How about you simply test it?

Comment: @GabeSechan what did you mean my applicaiton permission? Unity?

Comment: I mean the Android app you're trying to build.  Unity is a framework inside that app.  Somewhere something in your system is generating an AndroidManifest.xml with a list of permissions it requires.  One of those may be the MOCK_LOCATIONS permission.  If so, it should work.  If not, it won't see the mocks.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes android allows mocking. and GNSS COmmander page mock setting is like this: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eHuwFtc82WtFQyr_TTaESrEY0QfMtw2FQHkz5bMaSyl_gwFcgzq3uWneZigV1HUbD3S5=w1920-h966